# image_picker problem: unsupported file format 'public.heic'

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I'm using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) library to pick image from gallery. But I'm getting the following error:

```
findWriterForTypeAndAlternateType:119: unsupported file format 'public.heic'
```

My simple code:

```
onTap: () async {
     final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
     final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
     print(image?.mimeType);
},
```

I'm testing the code on real device which is iPad with iOS 15.1. I also added NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription to info.plist.

image_picker version: 0.8.4+4

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: I also receive this message in my logs when using the image_picker library, but for me it all still works and a valid XFile is produced. The message is caused because image_picker doesn't support iOS's HEIC format, but for me the library just automatically converts the image to a JPG and still delivers it to me. This issue has been reported to the Flutter team under https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103248